# Infinite boot loop after installing second HDD in Laptop

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, lenovo-laptop

I installed a second hard drive on my laptop, replacing the DVD-RW with a HDD caddy. Then, I made a clean install of Linux Mint. Whenever I boot or restart my laptop, it goes into an infinite boot loop, showing me the Lenovo splash screen, then booting again. How can I make it boot into Mint automatically?

Comment: Did you put linux on the new HDD or the old one?

Comment: I put it into the new one (an SSD), then I swapped them physically, then I reinstalled Mint into the SSD. Still nothing :(